# Error with Array.map() in IE11

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashmap

I have this code:

```
var labelsPrint= new Array();

var vector = labelsPrint.map((el) => el.id);
```

IE11 give me a error, because lost the datas. Do you know an other way for make this .map?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

IE11 has ES5, not ES6

```
var vector = labelsPrint.map(function (el) { return el.id; });
```